# Is there a way to copy folders on Android? (non-files)

Tags: java, android

I'd like to include the directory copy function in the application I'm creating. I'm asking you because I can't find a copy of the directory on Android.

There is a problem trying to get the code that works well on Java to Android.

```
public void copyDirectory(){
    File folder1 = new File(srcDir);
    File folder2 = new File(dstDir);

    File[] target_file = folder1.listFiles();
    for (File file : target_file) {
        File temp = new File(folder2.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + file.getName());
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            temp.mkdir();
        } else {
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(temp) ;
                byte[] b = new byte[4096];
                int cnt = 0;
                while((cnt=fis.read(b)) != -1){
                    fos.write(b, 0, cnt);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                try {
                    fis.close();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.FileOutputStream.close()' on a null object reference
        at com.xxx.xxx.FileCombination.copyDirectory(FileCombination.java:54)

Comment: `public void copyDirectory()` A function whithout parameters? Please start making it with parameters. Like `public void copyDirectory(String srcDir, String dstDir)` or `public void copyDirectory(File srcFolder, File dstFolder)`. After that show which pathts you exactly use. And on which Android version. mkdirs() returns false or true. Check what it returns. And dont call mkdirs() if the directory already existst.

Comment: `File[] target_file = folder1.listFiles();` That is not the target. Those are the source files. Better: `File[] srcfiles[] = folder1.listFiles();` And then `temp` is the target.

Comment: And make the function recursive. You are not copying the files in subdirectories of the source.

Answer (score 0):

In your Code in this line

```
File folder1 = new File(srcDir);
```

what is the value of srcDir .I think this is not 
getting the right value thats why the folder is not 
created when you call the

```
temp.mkdir();
```

So my suggestion will be get the right srcDir as follow

```
srcDir = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

and in temp variable

```
File temp =new File(srcDir,file.getName());
if(!temp.exists())
{
temp.mkDir();
}
```

Please try this I think it will work.

Comment: Check the return value of mkdir(). And dont continue if it returns false.